# Error running socket processor when endpoint is called

Tags: java, spring, ssl, bouncycastle

My spring-boot application is giving me this error out of nowhere when I call one rest endpoint.

I do not have bouncycastle specified in my pom...

My JDK is 1.8.0_302, someone has suggestions?

```
 20-10-2022 10:02:25.576 [ERROR] - [https-jsse-nio-27100-exec-1] o.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint     : Error running socket processor
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.PSSSigner.generateSignature(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.PSSSignatureSpi.engineSign(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineSign(Signature.java:1382)
    at java.security.Signature.sign(Signature.java:698)
    at sun.security.ssl.DHServerKeyExchange$DHServerKeyExchangeMessage.<init>(DHServerKeyExchange.java:162)
    at sun.security.ssl.DHServerKeyExchange$DHServerKeyExchangeProducer.produce(DHServerKeyExchange.java:481)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T12ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1020)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:727)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:693)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:377)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:968)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:955)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:902)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.tasks(SecureNioChannel.java:443)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeUnwrap(SecureNioChannel.java:507)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:238)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1616)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: You dont have `bouncycastle` but one of your dependencies might have

Comment: thanks! Turned out it was included in com.ibm.mq package and the solution was to upgrade bouncycastle above 1.6.5 cause before there was a bug